# Create an Object of redux class

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Below is my redux class.

```
class TestClass extends Component
    {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    }
    method(){
    return "Hello"
    }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {

        };
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
        return bindActionCreators({

        },dispatch)
    }

    export default connect(
        mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps
    )(TestClass);
```

When I tried it throws an error saying the store is missing enclose in provider or pass store explicitly

I want to create an object of this class and call the function method using that object!

Thanks

Comment: error message is telling you good: https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-passing-the-store-down-explicitly-via-props

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error:

> Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(*MyApp*)".
>   Either wrap the root component in a ,
>   or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(*MyApp*)".

It means that you didn't provide the store to your component.

Basic checklist to do it:

1. First of all, you need (and it's not the purpose of this post)

   A. a reducer function 'myReducer'.
   B. an object for your initial store 'myInitialState'.
2. Now you can create your Redux store

   *example:*

   ```
   import { createStore } from 'redux';

   configureStore = () => {
       const store = createStore(myReducer, myInitialState);
       return store;
   };

   const store = configureStore();
   ```
3. and finally it's time to give the store to your component:

   3.1. first solution, wrap the root component in a :

   ```
   import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
   ```

   in your JSX:

   ```
    <Provider store={store}>
       <SomeOtherComponent>
           <MyComponent />
       </SomeOtherComponent>
    </Provider>
   ```

   3.2. Or easier solution for short term, explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(MyApp)":

   in your JSX:

   ```
    <SomeOtherComponent>
       <MyComponent store={store} />
    </SomeOtherComponent>
   ```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but this isn't what I wanted. I wanted to create an object of the redux class and pass the store explicitly.